# Which terminal should I connect it to for a “C” wire on an american standard AM4A0A30

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I'm trying to connect a 3rd gen Nest thermostat. I have a 2 zoned heat and 1 zone AC. The zone with this thermostat has a boiler wired Rw, W1 and HVAC wired Rc, G, Y1. It's summer so I'm only using the AC currently, but the thermostat seems to be drawing power from my 2 zone relay attached to my boiler even when the heat isn't on. It keeps triggering it on and off constantly. I called NEST support and they said I need a C wire that needs to come from the HVAC not the boiler.[image]

I'm looking at the wiring for the HVAC and I'm not sure terminal to attach the common wire to.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the hydronic boiler feeding radiators, a coil in the air handler, or both?

Comment: Also, is pulling a thermostat cable with more wires between the air handler and the thermostat an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I'm confused with the first question. The boiler for heat is a separate unit in the basement. The air handler is only for AC. There is no connection between systems.   

Yes pulling a cable with more wires is an option. But I was hoping to use a FAST-STAT Common Maker Thermostat Wire Extender from amazon which would use my existing wire configuration without needing to pull a new one.
But, I'd need to know what terminal to connect the common wire to at the hair handler.

Answer (score 2):

The "B" terminal is your common. You will definitely need to pull more wires. And YES you need a common for the nest to work.

To make your life much simpler, you can add a FAST-STAT Common Maker Thermostat Wire Extender (Adds a Common "C" Connection).